# How do I trigger ngModelChange on custom input?

Tags: angular

I have a custom input component, here is the code:

html:

```
 <input class='ctrl__counter-input' maxlength='10' type='text' [value]="counterValue" [ngModel]="counterValue"
               (ngModelChange)="onKey(input)">
```

typescript:

```
export class BaCounterInput {


    @Input('minimum') minimum: number;
        @Input('maximum') maximum: number;
        @Input('counterValue') counterValue: number;
        @Output() counterResult = new EventEmitter<number>();
    /* rest of component*/

onKey( event: any ): void {
        console.log(event);
        let testNumber = parseInt(event);

        if ( !isNaN(testNumber) ) {
            ((testNumber >= this.minimum) && (testNumber <= this.maximum) ) ? this.setCounter(testNumber) : this.counterValue;
            this.counterResult.emit(this.counterValue);
        }
        this.counterResult.emit(this.counterValue);
    }
}
```

And this is how i am calling it in the host component:

```
<label for="sale_year_input">Purchase Price</label>
            <input-counter id="sale_year_input"
                           [minimum]="1" [maximum]="10"
                           [counterValue]="sale_year"
                           (counterResult)="sale_year"
                           [(ngModel)]="sale_year"
                           (ngModelChange)="calculateOutput()" ngDefaultControl>
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to trigger calculateOut().
It is worth noting that sale_year is an input and an output at the same time, and when it changes, the calculateOutput() function should be triggered. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: In your OnKey(input) event, you can emit the event like counterResult.emit() to call calculateOutput in your parent component.

Comment: @AliBaig I updated my question to show the implementation of the onkey

Answer (score 2):

`ngModelChange` should take `$event` as it's input, then you can store it accordingly:

```
<input class='ctrl__counter-input' maxlength='10' type='text' [value]="counterValue" [ngModel]="counterValue"
               (ngModelChange)="onKey($event)">
```

...

```
onKey(newValue): void {
    this.data = newValue;
    // ....
}
```

this event will be triggered on each key press

Comment: does it matter if I am emitting the number only that is entered?